# Prove $V=W\oplus \operatorname{Ker}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a linear transformation on a linear space $V$, $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r$ is a set of bases of $\operatorname{Im}A$,  $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r$ are the original images of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r$. Let $W=\langle\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r\rangle$, then prove
$$V=W\oplus \operatorname{Ker}A.$$

Below is my idea.

It's not difficult to see $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r$  is linearly independent
Let $S$ be the complementary space of $W$, then $V=W\oplus S$. If $\gamma \in V$ and $\gamma\neq 0$, let $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2$, where $\gamma_1\in W, \gamma_2\in S$. So $A(\gamma)=A(\gamma_1)+A(\gamma_2)\in \operatorname{Im}A\implies A(\gamma_2)=0$. So $S\subset \operatorname{ker}A$. But I don't know how to get a further step.

I think $A$ looks like some kind of projection, its matrix under two different sets of bases of V $\{\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_r,\cdots\}$ and $ \{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r,\cdots\}$ looks like $\operatorname{diag}\{1,1,\cdots,0,0,\cdots\}$.

Can there be a clearer proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The step $A(\gamma_2)=0$ is wrong. E.g. consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ to be the multiplication with $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. We can choose $W:=\langle e_1 \rangle$ and $S:=\langle e_2 \rangle$. But $A(S) \neq 0$. Try instead to choose $S$ in a proper way and show then, that $W$ and $S$ are a direct sum (and span $V$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\in W\cap\ker A$. Then $v=\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i\beta_i\in\ker A$ and hence
$$0=A(v)=\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i\alpha_i,$$
thus each $\lambda_i=0$ and $v=0$.
To conclude observe that
$$\text{dim}(W+\ker A)=\text{dim}(W)+\text{dim}(\ker A)=\text{dim}(\text{Im}A)+\text{dim}(\ker A)=\text{dim}(V).$$

**Edit:**
If $V$ has infinite dimension we can't conclude the result using the dimension formula. This proof works for an arbitrary $V$, without depending on its dimension's cardinality.
The part of the trivial intersection of the subspaces is analogous. In this case, take $v\in V$.
Since $A(v)\in\text{Im}(A)$ we may write
$$A(v)=\sum_{i}\mu_i\alpha_i=\sum_{i}\mu_i A(\beta_i),$$
from where it follows that
$$A(v-\sum_{i}\mu_i\beta_i)=0.$$
Then $v-\sum_{i}\mu_i\beta_i\in\ker A$ and the result follows since each $\beta_i$ lies in $W$.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional, does this dimension formula still hold?

Comment: @Ychen I don't think so. I did another proof for if $V$ is infinite dimensional.